# Postgresql's check_function_bodies in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is there something like Postgresql's `check_function_bodies` for MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't available.

MySQL doesn't do anything much except basic syntax checking when defining stored procedures and functions. It's important to actually run that code to make sure you got it right in MySQL.